# mysql drop database which exists with same name

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have got a weird state in my mysql/ mariadb server.

When I execute `show databases;` it gets following result:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| MYDATABASENAME         |
| mydatabasename         |
```

And when I execute `drop database MYDATABASENAME;` then the database `mydatabasename` lowercase one gets dropped and not the uppercase one. If I then execute the `drop database MYDATABASENAME;` again it says

> ERROR 1008 (HY000): Can't drop database 'mydatabasename'; database doesn't
>   exist

**UPDATE**

In my.cnf I had set lower_case_table_names=1 which caused the mysql server to handle all tables/ databases in lower case format. See my answer below.

My question is now, how can I drop the uppercase database "MYDATABASENAME"?

Comment: Try a case sensitive collaction in your drop command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have set `lower_case_table_names=1` in your `my.cnf` then mysql handles/ stores all tables and databases in lower case format. So disabling the property, then executing the drop command again fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is best not to try to override the OS-based default value for `lower_case_table_names`.

MySQL/MariaDB depend on file and directory names based on table and database names.  But Windows ignores case; *nix does not.